# Multiple optional @RequestParam not fetching Data in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, pagination

I want to paginate response Data in Spring boot project. According to business logic, I added multiple RequestParam. All is ok, if I pass value for all request Param i.e Gender and Country. But if I don't give value either one or both, I get 500 status code, although I make gender and Country requestParam as optional. It means,

if I hit

http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users?page=1&country=Russia&gender=M,

I get response with pagination.

But if I hit

http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users?page=1&gender=M

http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users?page=1&country=Russia

http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users?page=1.

I get exception

Here is my code.

`UserRepository.kt`

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository: JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query(
        nativeQuery = true,
        value = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE gender =:gender AND country =:country"
    )
    fun getUsers(gender: String?, country: String?, pageable: Pageable): Page<User>

}
```

`UserServiceImpl.kt`

```
@Service
class UserServiceImpl(
    @Autowired private val userRepository: UserRepository
): UserService {

    override fun getUsers(gender: String?, country: String?, pageable: Pageable): Page<User> {
        return userRepository.getUsers(gender, country, pageable)
    }

}
```

`UserController.kt`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(
    path = [
        "/api/v1/"
    ]
)
class UserController(
    @Autowired private val userService: UserService
) {

    @GetMapping("users")
    fun getUsers(
        @RequestParam(required = true) page: Int,
        @RequestParam(required = false) gender: String?,
        @RequestParam(required = false) country: String?
    ): Page<User> {
        return userService.getUsers(gender, country, PageRequest.of(page, 10))
    }

}
```

`response`

```
{
    "status": "500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
    "message": "Internal server error occurs",
    "error": "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet"
}
```

Comment: Add default value to country and gender field. It will fix the issue.

Comment: For dynamic queries with varying parameters use predicates instead of a method to execute the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem by JpaSpecificationExecutor which helps to create dynamic query. The code is given bellow.

`UserSpecification.kt`

```
import com.example.demo.entity.User
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root
import java.text.MessageFormat.format

object UserSpecification {

    fun countryContains(country: String?): Specification<User>? {
        return country?.let {
            Specification { root: Root<User>, _: CriteriaQuery<*>, criteriaBuilder: CriteriaBuilder ->
                criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("country"), format("%{0}%", country))
            }
        }
    }

    fun genderContains(gender: String?): Specification<User>? {
        return gender?.let {
            Specification { root: Root<User>, _: CriteriaQuery<*>, criteriaBuilder: CriteriaBuilder ->
                criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get<String>("gender"), gender)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`UserRepository.kt`

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository: JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {

}
```

`UserServiceImpl.kt`

```
@Service
class UserServiceImpl(
    @Autowired private val userRepository: UserRepository
): UserService {

    override fun getUsers(gender: String?, country: String?, pageable: Pageable): Page<User> {
        return userRepository.findAll(
            where(
                countryContains(country)
            ).and(
                genderContains(gender)
            ), pageable
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use jdbcTemplate here like this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE gender = :gender AND country = :country";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("gender", gender);
params.put("country", country);
Map<String, Long> results = new HashMap<>();
// Execute Your Query Here like: users = jdbcTemplate.query(query, params, ...
```

for thos params you can check if for example gender not null append gender = :gender to main query.

Answer (score 0):

yes the error you're getting is correct because the values for your query doesn't exist i would suggest you make the following changes ...

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository: JpaRepository<User, Long> {

@Query(
    nativeQuery = true,
    value = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE country =:country"
)
fun getUsersWithoutGender( country: String?, pageable: Pageable): Page<User>

 @Query(
    nativeQuery = true,
    value = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE gender =:gender AND country =:country"
)
fun getUsersWithoutCountry(gender: String?, pageable: Pageable): Page<User>

 @Query(
    nativeQuery = true,
    value = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE gender =:gender AND country =:country"
)
fun getUsers(gender: String?, country: String?, pageable: Pageable): Page<User>

@Query(
    nativeQuery = true,
    value = "SELECT * FROM user_info"
)
fun getallUsers(): Page<User>

}
```

and in your controller

```
RestController
@RequestMapping(
path = [
    "/api/v1/"
]
)
class UserController(
@Autowired private val userService: UserService
) {

@GetMapping("users")
fun getUsers(
    @RequestParam(required = true) page: Int,
    @RequestParam(required = false) gender: String?,
    @RequestParam(required = false) country: String?
): Page<User> {

if(country == null && gender =! null){
    return userService.getUsersWithoutCountry(gender,PageRequest.of(page, 10))
} else if (gender== null && country =! null){
    return userService.getUsersWithoutGender(country,PageRequest.of(page, 10))
}else if (gender && country == null){
    return userService.getAllUsers()
}else {
    return userService.getUsers(gender, country, PageRequest.of(page, 10))    
}
}

}
```

this way all your queries will run as they don't have a null value.

Comment: Thanks brother for your response. I have already written this code. But I want to solve the problem generically. Suppose more and more param has come in future. then it will be tough to handle